# Change one material on Object with two materials

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[(Image: model with two materials)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9CZV.png)I create a simple model in Blender, it have two materials. I exported it to .obj file and export to Unity project. I need to write a script which should change one models material from two it have. But how I can do this with script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple options.

I will suggest you to do as the following :

In your script that changes one of your material, call a function like

```cs
public void ChangeMaterial(Material m, int index){
    GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[index] = m;
}
```

If you want to change your material multiple times, you'd probably want to cache the `Renderer` component.

There is a full script example

```cs
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Renderer _renderer;

    private void Start(){
        _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    public void ChangeMaterial(Material m, int index){
        _renderer.materials[index] = m;
    }
}
```